# Solve $\log_9 (a) + \log_{12} (b) = \log_{16} (a+b)$ for $a/b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The question:
$$\log_9 (a) + \log_{12} (b) = \log_{16} (a+b)$$
solve for $a/b$.

It gives hints:
put it all in terms of x.

$$9^x=a$$

$$12^x=b$$

$$16^x=a+b$$

Now prove that:
$b^2=a(a+b)$ I did and it does equal.

Then it tells me to divide both sides of $b^2=a(a+b)$ by $b^2$. Here is what I got:

$$\frac{b^2}{b^2} = \frac{a(a+b)}{b^2}$$

$$1 = \frac{a}{b}*\frac{a+b}{b}$$

$$\frac{1}{a+b}*\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$\frac{1}{b(a+b)}=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$\frac{1}{12^x16^x}=\frac{9^x}{12^x}$$

$$\frac{1}{192^x}=\frac{3^x}{4^x}$$

$$1=\frac{576^x}{4^x}$$

$$1=144^x$$

$$x=\log_{144}(1)=\frac{\log(1)}{\log(144)}=0$$

Therefore:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{9^x}{12^x}=\frac{9^0}{12^0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

so $a/b = 1$ is what I got. But I looked this question up on the internet and apparently it has to be $a/b=$the golden ratio (there was a hint at the end of the revision sheet saying $a/b$ and sunflower). But I can't figure it out. I always end up with $a/b = 1$ whatever I do. Help please.

Comment: You can't put everything to be equal to $x$ because $x+x \ne x$. You get my point?

Comment: i don't understand sorry.

Comment: Well, if you say let $\log_9 a$, $\log_{12} b$, $\log_{16} (a+b)$ all be equal to $x$, it follows that  $x = 2x$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: the revision sheet says to do it. Let x=log_9(a) = log_12(b)=log_16(a+b). epress a, b a+b in terms of x. Or did I do that wrong? If so then what is the right way?

Comment: i think there is something wrong in line 3

Comment: The exercise in the first place is wrong...

Comment: I realize this was asked over a year ago, but there is a disparity between the question asked and the answers provided (either OP asked the wrong question, or answers don't address the question on hand). OP asks to solve for $\frac{a}{b}$ if $\log_9 (a) + \log_{12} (b) = \log_{16} (a+b)$, but solutions provided are for if $\log_9 (a) = \log_{12} (b) = \log_{16} (a+b)$. If this is the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : You have the following equality
$$1 = \frac{a}{b} \times \frac{a+b}{b}, $$
and observe that $\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{b} = \frac{a}{b} + 1$, now we define $Y=\frac{a}{b}$, to get that $Y$ is a solution of
$$1 = Y\times(Y+1)\qquad \Leftrightarrow\qquad Y^2+Y-1=0. $$

Comment: how does 1=a/b * a=b/b turn into a+b/b = a/b+1?

Comment: @Downvoter,  please explain your downvote.

Comment: i didn't downvote.....

Comment: I didn't say that. I've edited my answer, now you understand why $(a+b)/b=(a/b)+1$?

Comment: so i am stuck where do i g from y^2 +y -1 =0? I tried factorising it and i couldnt.

Comment: To solve this kind of equations, please look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: actually i figured out i had to use the quadratic formula. Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.